# wmsgetfeatureinfo and GWC

Tags: openlayers-2, getfeatureinfo, geowebcache

I have one layer group *glayer1* cached and I get the tiles from GWC. In *glayer1*, some layers are not queryable.

I have *layer2* which is queryable and contains short information.

*glayer1* is visible, *layer2* is in the map but is not visible.

How can I use `wmsgetfeatureinfo` triggered in *glayer1* but returning information from *layer2* as an elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

When user clicks on a map for getting info from layer "topp:states" through GetFeatureInfo the standard request which is created looks like this:

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?bbox=-100.00,35.00,-99.99,35.01&styles=&format=jpeg&request=GetFeatureInfo&layers=topp:states&query_layers=topp:states&width=2&height=2&x=1&y=1

If you want to get info from some other layer (here "ne:ne_10m_admin_0_countries") you must a) use another layer in &query_layers parameter b) add this layer to &layers parameter because &query_layers must be a subset of &layers.

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?bbox=-100.00,35.00,-99.99,35.01&styles=&format=jpeg&request=GetFeatureInfo&layers=topp:states,ne:ne_10m_admin_0_countries&query_layers=ne:ne_10m_admin_0_countries&width=2&height=2&x=1&y=1

This is how it works. Unfortunately I can't show you elegant JavaScript code for redirecting GetFeatureInfo into another layer.